# How can you synthesize speech using Phonemes for iOS

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm working on an application that requires the use of a text to speech synthesizer.  Implementing this was rather simple for iOS using AVSpeechSynthesizer.  However, when it comes to customizing synthesis, I was directed to documentation about speech synthesis for an OSX only API, which allows you to input phoneme pairs, in order to customize word pronunciation.  Unfortunately, this interface is not available on iOS.

I was hoping someone might know of a similar library or plugin that might accomplish the same task.  If you do, it would be much appreciated if you would lend a hand.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVSpeechSynthesizer` for iOS is not capable (out of the box) to work with phonemes. `NSSpeechSynthesizer` is [capable of it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechSynthesizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSpeechSynthesizer/phonemesFromText:), but that's not available on iOS.

You can create an algorithm that produces short phonemes, but it would be incredibly difficult to make it sound good by any means.

Comment: Thanks for the information... This is really unfortunate news.  I have found a few paid software solutions that would be able to accomplish this task much more easily than implementing the algorithm myself.  However, I was wondering if you might be aware of some free software solutions that are capable of the task at hand?

Comment: I do not know of any free software for this. The simplest solution that I can imagine would be to create a dictionary of phoneme pairs as strings using an IPA representation for keys, breaking the text down into said phoneme pairs, and then constructing a string based off of that modified text.

Answer (score 1):

> ... allows you to input phoneme pairs, in order to customize word pronunciation. Unfortunately, this interface is not available on iOS.

This kind of interface is definitely [available on iOS](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis): in your device settings *(iOS 12)*, once the menu `General` - `Accessibility` - `Speech` - `Pronunciations` is reached: 
[image]

1. Select the '+' icon to add a new phonetic element.
2. Name this new element in order to quickly find it later on.
3. Tap the microphone icon.
4. Vocalize an entire sentence or a single word.
5. Listen to the different system proposals.
6. Validate your choice with the 'OK' button or cancel to start over.
7. Tap the back button to confirm the new created phonetic element.
8. Find all the generated elements in the Pronunciations page.

[image]
Following the steps above, you will be able to **synthesize speech using phonemes for iOS**.